# Bootstrap btn group height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>Min: <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" title="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign glyphiconFormButton"></span></label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="question[nr][text][min]">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" name="question[nr][text][min]" class="form-control input-number" value="5" min="1" max="50">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="question[nr][text][min]">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>Max: <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" title="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign glyphiconFormButton"></span></label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="question[nr][text][max]">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" name="question[nr][text][max]" class="form-control input-number" value="30" min="10" max="50">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="question[nr][text][max]">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick="deleteQuestion()">Remove</button>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

All include I get from there:  [enter link description here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.3.5.zip)
and folder **dist**

1. **Why buttons "-" and "+" are not have the same height as input field**?
2. **If I can ask second question, how to put 'remove' button to the same line as '-',input,'+'** ?

Update:
I see that corrent buttons have size 14x20 my is 14x14 but why?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me - http://www.bootply.com/DtkJWFDG3Y

Comment: add button `remove` in your code example

Comment: Added, but i dont understand this 'inline' problem :0

Comment: Do you have a problem with a specific broswer ? Works fine with FF. Maybe it can be a css clash but then you should inspect the whole DOM hierarchy and your CSS. You may have somthing that is brearking it.

Comment: @Anonymous I change the main code. It still return the same as on image. Whats wrong?

Comment: @Thomas Banderas, you have default bootstrap buttons and `height` depends of `font-size: 14px` class `.btn`, width depends of content button, if few words inside, width increase

Comment: @IgorIvancha but why the same code on bootply works?

Comment: @IgorIvancha If i use this `<button /*params*/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>` result is as you see, but if i use this:
`<button /*params*/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>h</button>` button height is ok, I mean that when I write one letter into button I get the correct height, but how to make correct height without adding letter? --- Ohm okey, when I remove line-height: value from glyphicon it seems to be OK but in input-group, on rest items in page glyphicon are uneven...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see issue with your `+` and `-` buttons.
Second question, because `inputs` have `labels`! quick fix, to add `padding-top` to your `remove button`:

```
<div class="col-md-1 custom">
  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick="deleteQuestion()">Remove</button>
</div>

.custom {
  padding-top: 26px;
}
```

in jsfiddle I changed `md`-classes to `xs`-classes to use small screen, change it back for you!
[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/2ues18vm/1/)

Comment: to create your own `class` is a good way! you know what it class means and  you can increase or reduce it when you need. I do this way and if I knew better solution, I'd say about it!